# Unable to connect to wireless adhoc/hotspot with Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, wireless, network-manager

I have the following Wireless adaptor
Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
Ever since I installed Ubuntu 11.10, I am unable to connect to an ad-hoc network. I assume it is not getting the ip address. Anybody with the same Wireless adaptor facing this issue on Ubuntu 11.10 (Shell) ? This used to work perfectly in Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: I'm having the same problems as OP - can't connect to Android mobile hotspot. What part of the output would you like to usee ? My wireless interface product: AR242x/AR542x. Vendor: Atheros. Bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0. config: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=3.0.0-16-generic firmware=n/a wireless=IEEE 802.11bg

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Go to network connections -> Wireless
choose the network you want to connect
select edit->ipv6-settings->ignore

A technical note:
 We can use our wifi adapter (NIC) in four modes: managed, monitor, ad-hoc and Access Point(master).

Managed: It is the default mode. It helps us to connect to access points only. So if you are connected to AP it means your card is in managed mode.

Monitor: In this mode you don't connect to any of the networks but simply catch the packets in air. Usually used for hacking wifi passwords.

Ad-hoc: It is like a P2P connection. If two machines are connected via an ad-hoc connection both the machines should be in ad-hoc mode , using managed mode you can't connect to an ad-hoc but only access point.

Access Point: In this your card behaves like a router/access point. You need HostAP daemon to create an AP.

Now, if you can't create an ad-hoc connection this means your driver does not support ad-hoc mode and hence you can't connect to an ad-hoc network. But you should always be able to connect to an AP.

Comment: i tried this and it didn't work =(

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure connection network is available in your list. If not then enter these lines in terminal:

   ```
    sudo rfkill unblock all
   ```

   This one enable your wireless networking.
2. Edit connection > Select network which you want to connect and Edit. In IP section try manual for adhoc. For example:

   > IP: 192.0.0.1
   >   netmask: 255.255.255.0
   >   gateway: 0.0.0.0

   and then connect your ad-hoc network